# Why does SKLabelNode increment too much on Contact? (Swift)

Tags: swift, physics, bitmask

I am trying to have my Label to increment +1 every time a sprite makes contact with a Contact node, but it increments by large numbers like +23.  I think what is happening is that its taking into account every millisecond that the sprite is touching the node, but i don't know how to fix it.
Here is my Label node code within DidMoveToView:

```
score = 0
        scoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"[z] Arista Light")
        scoreLabelNode.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/4)
        scoreLabelNode.zPosition = 100
        scoreLabelNode.fontSize = 500
        scoreLabelNode.alpha = 0.03
        scoreLabelNode.text = String(score)
        self.addChild(scoreLabelNode)
```

here is my contact node:

```
var contactNode = SKNode()
        contactNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + asteroidTexture.size().height / 15 + rocket.size.width, y: 0.0)
        contactNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake( asteroid.size.width/16, self.frame.size.height*2 ))
        contactNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        contactNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = scoreCategory
        contactNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = rocketCategory
        contactNode.runAction(asteroidsMoveAndRemove)
        moving.addChild(contactNode)
```

and here is my code where when my rocket sprite makes contact with the contactNode it increments:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if moving.speed > 0 {
            if ( contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory || ( contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory ) == scoreCategory {
                // Rocket has contact with score entity
                score++
                scoreLabelNode.text = String(score)
                println("HIT")
            }
            else{
                gameOver()
            }
        }
```

*'moving' is when my asteroid sprites are moving, the contact nodes move with it*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not every millisecond, but instead every frame, and that's why you likely end up with numbers like +23 (The collision is taking place for a 1/3 of a second and if it's running at 60 FPS that is about 20 or so frames).

One thing you could do is subclass `SKNode` into an actual `ContactNode` class that has a property `hasBeenStruck` that is initially set to `false` or something to that extent.

Then when you check contact, you first check to see if `hasBeenStruck` is false.  If it is, register the hit and update the score and then set that `ContactNode`'s `hasBeenStruck` property to `true`.  This way, on the next 20 or so checks to see if contact has happened, it won't keep updating the label because the if condition has failed.

However, if your game allows a user to hit the same `ContactNode` twice and get score both times, this isn't a complete solution.  If that is the case, you could use a timer or "invincibility" period for the given `ContactNode`.

Comment: Great, hope everything works for you!  Make sure to close the question/Select an answer if everything is answered and working properly :)